# Checking a Bool in a different class

Tags: c++

I'm certain this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to find a straight answer for my issue.

So, in the file GameScreenLevel1.ccp, I have a bool like this:

```
bool GameScreenLevel1::LevelComplete()
{
    if(mEnemies.empty() && mFruit.empty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in the file GameScreenManager.ccp's Update function, I attempt to call it to see if it is true.

```
if(GameScreenLevel1.LevelComplete() == true)
    {
        ChangeScreen(SCREEN_LEVEL2);
    }
```

I know I can't use `(GameScreenLevel1::LevelComplete() == true)` due to the bool being nonstatic, so I want to know how I can reference this bool from a different class.

Thanks for reading and answering!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, this question doesn't really make any sense. That is not "a `bool`"; it is a member function of a class that returns a `bool`. You need an object of type `GameScreenLevel1`. I suggest reading again the chapter in your C++ book about classes.

Comment: So the line should read something like if (screenInstance.LevelComplete()) ...

Comment: You can simplify the body of `LevelComplete` to `return mEnemies.empty() && mFruit.empty();` Also, `if (foo == true)` can be simplified to `if (foo)`

Comment: @FredOverflow: Perhaps let's come back to subjective approaches to "simplifying" things when the OP has a little more experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is, however if you are simply trying to check for the return of `LevelComplete()`, then what you wrote is almost fine. It can be condensed to something like:

```
bool GameScreenLevel1::LevelComplete()
{
    return (mEnemies.empty() && mFruit.empty());
}
```

Then in your `Gamescreenmanager.cpp` you can do something like this:

```
GameScreenLevel1 GameScreenLevel1_(/*constructors*/);
/*extra stuff */
if(GameScreenLevel1_.LevelComplete()) {
    /* Code here */
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean either, I'm really not very experienced with C++ at all. My constructor looks like

Comment: You have to initialize your object before you can access the member variables.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter, and didn't make the edit in time.

I don't quite understand what you mean either, I'm really not very experienced with C++ at all. I can't tell what the `GameScreenLevel1 GameScreenLevel1_(/*constructors*/);` is exactly doing, to me that looks like it isn't doing anything.

Would it work if I converted LevelComplete into a void, and had a bool defined in GameScreenLevel1 (call it 'complete'), that was set to true or false depending on the if statement in my current code, and then reference that instead?

Comment: It seems to be like you are missing a crucial piece of OOP knowledge. A class is nothing more than the blueprint of an object. If you want to work with an object that is of `GameScreenLevel1` type, you need to initialize that object. Initialization is done via a constructor. When I wrote `/*constructors*/`, I meant to input w/e parameters your constructor takes. That piece of code creates a `GameScreenLevel_` object, which you can then access member variables/functions with.

Comment: Aha, I see. I already have a constructor in GameScreenManager `GameScreenManager::GameScreenManager(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SCREENS startScreen)
{
 mRenderer = renderer;
 mCurrentScreen = NULL;

 //Ensure first screen is set up.
 ChangeScreen(startScreen);
}`

, do I modify this then?